# Data from form not written into sqlite DB

Tags: python, html, apache, sqlite, cgi

I am trying to write data from a html form into a Sqlite database (d1). But the code does not connect/create the DB. I have checked Apache logs and there was no error. Can anyone help me why this is happening?

Python code (sc1.cgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print ( "/nContent-Type: text/html\n\n" )

import cgi
import sqlite3 

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fn = form.getvalue('first_name')
ln = form.getvalue('last_name')

conn = sqlite3.connect('d1.db')
c = conn.cursor()
q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (first_name, last_name)"
c.execute(q)
q = "INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (fn, ln)
c.execute(q)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Form:

```
<body>
<form action = /path/to/sc1.cgi>
First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please check whether fn and ln are None.

Comment: They are not blank. I have already checked this with print statement.

Comment: Very likely, it does create the database file but in the directory that you don't expect. Change the `db1.db` with an absolute path and try again.

Comment: There is actually an absolute path there. Permissions are also not the issue since I am using a path with full rwx permissions.

Comment: `db1.db` is not an absolute path and rather relative. Absolute path would be something like `/var/data/db1.db` for the file placed in the `/var/data` folder.

Comment: Yes. I just removed the path from my code on SO to make it more readable. It's actullay: /tmp/d1.db

Comment: wrap the database code with `try/except` and see if any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is everything's there. All old inserted rows get printed on the browser. But I can't see the DB in /tmp.